# Not able to call a method in Class ; Getting runtime error

Tags: scala

Here is my code

```
scala> class Subjects {
     |     //The default Access Modifier of a vairable is 'public' #101
     |     private var subjects:List[String] = Nil
     |
     |     //Always Specify Return type for Readability #103
     |     //Here we are using Cons operator to prepend (Constant time)
     |     //A method with Side effect is also called 'Procedure' #103
     |     def addSubject(subject: String):Unit = { subjects = subject :: subjects }
     |
     |     def getSubjects():List[String] = subjects
     | }
defined class Subjects


scala>

scala> val obj = new Subjects
obj: Subjects = Subjects@d7c7c22

scala> obj.addSubject("Math")
<console>:47: error: value addSubject is not a member of Subjects
       obj.addSubject("Math")
```

I am trying to call `addSubject` which is a valid method in the `class` `Subjects` but getting Compilation error. What am I missing here?

Comment: That works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

How did you write the `Subjects` class in the console? Using `:paste`?

```
scala> val obj = new Subjects
obj: Subjects = Subjects@62ddbd7e

scala> obj.addSubject("Math")

scala> obj.getSubjects()
res1: List[String] = List(Math)
```

Comment: Nope...Did not use `:paste` Have typed-in directly in REPL. Have updated my question now. Also, I am using `spark-shell`

Comment: Oops. Terminated the Shell and opened it again..and everything works now...that is wierd